# AWS Lambda + Spring, how to load application.yml

Tags: java, spring, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, microservices

I have problem with customizing API gateway domain, for my restful app deployed on AWS lambda. Customized domain, works this way, that depending on basePath it chooses different APIs which finally touches Lambda. For example:

`api.mycustomdomain.com/view/ping` -> goes to application `view` with path `/view/ping`
`api.mycustomdomain.com/admin/ping` -> goes to application `admin` with path `/admin/ping`

I am using this example as boilerplate: https://github.com/awslabs/aws-serverless-java-container/tree/master/samples/spring/pet-store

What I would like to achieve is handler which depending on `Host` header strips prefix from request path.

I have prepared following application.yml file:

```
server:
  contextPath: "/view"
  productionHost: "api.mycustomdomain.com"
```

The problem/question is. How can I now load those into my Lambda function? Here is my naive try:

```
public class LambdaHandler implements RequestHandler<AwsProxyRequest, AwsProxyResponse> {
    SpringLambdaContainerHandler<AwsProxyRequest, AwsProxyResponse> handler;
    boolean isinitialized = false;

    @Value("${server.contextPath}")
    private String prefix;

    @Value("${server.productionHost}")
    private String productionHost;

    public AwsProxyResponse handleRequest(AwsProxyRequest awsProxyRequest, Context context) {
        if(awsProxyRequest.getHeaders().get("Host").equals(productionHost))
            awsProxyRequest.setPath(awsProxyRequest.getPath().substring(prefix.length()));

        if (!isinitialized) {
            isinitialized = true;
            try {
                handler = SpringLambdaContainerHandler.getAwsProxyHandler(PingPongApp.class);
            } catch (ContainerInitializationException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                return null;
            }
        }
        return handler.proxy(awsProxyRequest, context);
    }
}
```

Obviously this doesn't work, LambdaHandler is working out of Spring context.

Any ideas how can I deal with that?

Answer (score 0):

It seems you can not load those properties. Follow either of the 2 options given below.

1> You can add following bean in your configuration and that way you can autowire strings and use the way you are already using

```
@Bean
public static PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer propertyConfigInDev() {
return new PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer();
}
```

2>

```
public AwsProxyResponse..{
@Autowired
private Environment env;
..
    public AwsProxyResponse handleRequest{
    ..
    String contextPath = env.getRequiredProperty(“server.contextPath”));
    ...
    }
}
```

Comment: I tried first option. It didn't work. I think that the reason is that, the execution flow is: 1. api get request -> pass to lambda (LambdaHandler) -> 2. Lambda handler is invoking Spring, so I can't access @Value in LambdaHandler (spring is not initialized at this point).

Comment: I don't got your point in second proposal. You want me to overwrite AwsProxyResponse? Why?

Comment: no , i just said another way to retrieve properties. declaring env variable (org.springframework.core.env.Environoment) because something is wrong in loading properties here.